# Flexbox child exceeding its height in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I'm running into a strange Flexbox height issue in Safari.

In Chrome, the `center` div is at 100% height within the `body` div.

In Safari, the `center` div exceeds 100% height of its container; it looks like it takes an additional 50% of the `hero` element above it.

Has anyone seen this before?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

#hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#body {
  background: #CCC;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#center {
  background: #BBB;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="hero">hero</div>
  <div id="body">
    <a href="#">Left</a>
    <div id="center">center</div>
    <a href="#">Right</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `height: 100%;` on `#center` is the cause here. Instead you can use `align-items: stretch;` on the parent and then flex the children to center their contents:

```
#body {
  background: #CCC;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#body > * {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#center {
  background: #BBB;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdeQMM).

Comment: This was it! Thanks fredrivett.

Comment: Totally welcome. Feel free to mark as accepted if it does what you're after. Happy to help.

Comment: SO is telling me to wait 4 minutes, then I'll accept it :)

Comment: Cool no worries. Happy to have helped here, flexbox is confusing with its browser quirks.

Answer (score 1):

An initial setting on flex items is `flex-shrink: 1`. This means that flex items can shrink in order to fit inside the container. Chrome and Firefox apply this setting correctly, allowing the element to shrink to fit. Safari, apparently, has a different interpretation.

Here's a cross-browser solution:

```
#body {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Now `#center` will have the 100% of its adjusted parent.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

#hero {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#body {
  background: #CCC;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);  /* ADJUSTMENT */
  width: 100%;
}

#center {
  background: #BBB;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="hero">hero</div>
  <div id="body">
    <a href="#">Left</a>
    <div id="center">center</div>
    <a href="#">Right</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

A second solution would be to remove the height rule altogether from the `#center` child and instead use `align-self: stretch`.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

#hero {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#body {
  background: #CCC;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100% - 100px); /* ADJUSTMENT */
  width: 100%;
}

#center {
  background: #BBB;
  flex: 1;
  /* height: 100%; */
  align-self: stretch; /* ADJUSTMENT */
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="hero">hero</div>
  <div id="body">
    <a href="#">Left</a>
    <div id="center">center</div>
    <a href="#">Right</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. If the `#body` is set to 100%, why wouldn't it fit to the height of the viewport (it looks like it's about 50px short)?

Comment: It would if it could. First, it's bumping up against the `#hero` element. Second, it's subject to `align-items: center`. Remove those two obstacles, and it will occupy the full height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the prefixes depending of the browser, for example:

```
#hero {
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```